# How to execute ios appium script from jenkins or circleCI using emulator

Tags: ios, jenkins, automation, appium, appium-ios

How to execute ios appium script from jenkins or circleCI using emulator ?
Or we can do it with only real devices is it ?

How to execute ios appium script from jenkins or circleCI using emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a remote VM or real machine. On that all services related to appium iOS should be installed.

Then you should have the jenkins file that should connect to remote machine. Jenkins slave and agent should be installed on both machines.